# How to call objective-C function from a C function

Tags: c, objective-c, function

I'm trying to call an objective-C function from a C function but the code keeps crashing in objc_msgSend.

My objective-C class is a singleton and I'm using the following code.

```
void c_function(int arg0, const char *arg1)  
{  
   [[objc_class instance] testFunction:arg0 Arg1:arg1];  
}
```

The gdb shows the crash is happening when objective-C function is being invoked. How cal I call an objective-C function from within a c function?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean objective-c "method"? I can't see what's wrong with your code. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @Gary, did to you figure out how call your Objective-C singleton from C ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code as there are no special rules for calling objc methods from c functions.  If there is a crash in objc_msgSend, then refer to http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html.  The same thing would have happened if the objc line was in other objc code -- it's likely you forgot to retain the shared instance of your singleton.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out that the issue was happening due to some memory corruption in the usage of a thirdparty library.

Answer (score -1):

`[[objc_class instance] testFunction:arg0 Arg1:arg1];`

As you don’t provide further information:

*objec_class* is an instance, your singleton? And it handles the message *instance*? …

or

*objec_class* is really a class, having a class method *instance*? And this will give you another instance …

In other words, do you really have something like

`@interface class2 {
}
-(void) testFunction:(int)count Arg1:(const char *)args;
@end`

and

`@include "class2.h"
@interface objc_class {
}
-(class2*) instance {
}
-(void) testFunction:(int)count Arg1:(const char *)args;
@end`

or

`@include "class2.h"
@interface objc_class {
}
+(class2*) instance;
// be aware of the fact, instance (normaly) does not have
// access to any instance variables!`

to be included?

Your code doesn’t look like „hey, object(instance) singleton, I tell you to ‘instance’. Then I take your response and give it the message ‘testFunction:Arg1:’ (with some values inserted)”!

(Are you sure you understood objective c?)

Greetings

Comment: Are you sure you understood my question? :) I wasn't asking about the singleton pattern implementation but about how to call objective-C function from C function.

Answer (score -1):

## 1:

```
@interface class2 {

}

-(void) testFunction:(int)count Arg1:(const char *)args;

@end
```

## 2:

```
@include "class2.h"

@interface objc_class {

}

-(class2*) instance;

@end
```

## 3:

```
@include "class2.h"

@interface objc_class {

}

+(class2*) instance; // be aware of the fact, instance (normally) does not
                     // have access to any instance variables!
```